Changing Opacity in Beamer of Specific Parts of a Frame
Given the following setup of a frame in beamer
\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}
Definition
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}
Proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

imagine that I would like to have two slides where in the first slide everything has 'normal' opacity, while in the second the definition and the theorem get 0.5 opacity.
How is it possible to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I completely understand and if you check my history and my previous posts, I do not shy away from putting any extra work. Simply, I did not think it was important at all to put an MWE on this specific question in light of its generality, since the actual packages that should be in the preamble are completely irrelevant.

Creating a MWE would have made you spot the error in writing \end{theorem} Theorem \end{theorem} and would have saved other from having to guess how you might have defined your custom environments like proposition. Creating a working example from your code fragment, was several times as much work as actually answering your question.

Thanks for spotting the typo: I corrected it and I agree with you that it could have helped to spot the typo. But the point IMO was not about that. Once more, I completely understand the need of MWE in general and in some specific cases it is completely unavoidable. However, I also think there are exceptions and this specific post could belong to that category. But thanks also for the feedback with respect to this point.

"Creating a working example from your code fragment, was several times as much work as actually answering your question." Yep, I now see your point completely: it clicked. You are right. Even more, thanks a lot! :)

You could use overlays:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=50}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}<1>
Definition
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}
Proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}<1>
Theorem
\end{theorem}

\pause[2]

\end{frame}


\end{document}



Oh, that's the catch. I did not know it was possible to use overlays in that fashion (and, I completely see your point regarding the opacity, which can be indeed adjusted). Thanks a lot: really much appreciated!

I have an additional question: is it possible to use this in conjunction with the \onslide command? Say that after being the only non-transparent part, the text inside the Proposition environment becomes red (typically I would use \onslide to get such an outcome).

Of course, if needed, I can open a new question as a follow-up of this one.

@Kolmin Please ask a follow-up question which contains a ready-to-run example which replicates your situation.
